# how shoud i use initialize boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket? not using constructor (i need default construct) including(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)

Tags: c++, boost, serversocket

```
class Session
{
 public:
Session() <------ how should i use default constructor , this is error because boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket need initialize

Session(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, const int)

 private:
 boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
}
```

i wanna make this Session class for abstract class but
compiler need to initialize boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket

Comment: You can't, sockets need a context. You probably need to use a pointer (preferably a smart pointer) if you want session to be default constructible

Comment: Maybe std:: optional is a better idea than unique_ptr

Answer (score 3):

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` does not have a default constructor. That prevents your `Session` class from being default constructible as shown.  So, if `Session` needs to be default constructible, it cannot have a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` member, at least not the way you have declared it anyway.  `Session` will have to hold a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket*` pointer or a `std::optional<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>`.  Your default constructor can initialize it to `nullptr`/`std::nullopt`, and then you can construct the `socket` at a later time when you are ready to do so, after your default constructor has exited.

For example:

```cpp
class Session
{
public:
    Session() = default;

    Session(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, const int protocol) {
        initSocket(io_context, protocol);
    }

    void initSocket(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, const int protocol) {
        _socket = std::make_unique<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(io_context, protocol);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> _socket;
};
```

```cpp
class Session
{
public:
    Session() = default;

    Session(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, const int protocol) {
        initSocket(io_context, protocol);
    }

    void initSocket(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, const int protocol) {
        _socket = boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_context, protocol);
    }

private:
    std::optional<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> _socket;
};
```

Comment: thanks Remy 
i'll try use "std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> _socket"

i wanna remove my overlaping code :D

Comment: i love you! Remy Lebeau :)